# Images on screen are not placed well when going from portrait to landscape mode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating an app and everything is going smooth but when I rotate the device to landscape the images are not centered and it looks out of whack. Obviously there is a way to fix this. Any tips would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a NIB file to define your views, all of the objects are hard coded to a specific (X,Y) coordinate with length and width dimensions.

When you change orientation, the same coordinate and dimensions apply.

To change this, you will need to programmatically change the coordinates to whatever liking you find works best for your views.

Some example code from one of my apps:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Orientation Support

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) && self.portraitMode ) {
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = (&ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != nil) ? 
            ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32;

        if (self.bannerIsVisible)
            adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 268, 480, 12);
        else
            adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 318, 480, 32);

        backgroundImage.frame = CGRectMake(-30, -170, 700, 500);
        bottleImage.frame = CGRectMake(200, 30, 240, 240);
        searchBox.frame = CGRectMake(57, 48, 120, 31);
        pingButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 100, 133, 66);
        infoButton.frame = CGRectMake(444, 232, 18, 19);

        self.portraitMode = NO;
    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation) && !(self.portraitMode) ) {
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = (&ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != nil) ? 
            ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;

        if (self.bannerIsVisible)
            adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 410, 320, 50);
        else
            adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 460, 320, 50);

        backgroundImage.frame = CGRectMake(-190, -40, 700, 500);
        bottleImage.frame = CGRectMake(40, 165, 240, 240);
        searchBox.frame = CGRectMake(99, 56, 120, 31);
        pingButton.frame = CGRectMake(92, 99, 133, 66);
        infoButton.frame = CGRectMake(282, 374, 18, 19);

        self.portraitMode = YES;
    }
}
```

Here is some apple documentation on the coordinate system:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/CoordinateSystem.html

Hope this helps, cheers!